# Exclude hidden subdirectories from grep -r

Tags: grep, recursive

I have a svn local copy, i want to make a search on the string some_string.

```
$ grep some_string * -r
lang/en:some_string=Some string
lang/.svn/en:some_string=Some string
```

But if a go little further, it seems that first level hidden directories are excluded :

```
$ cd lang && grep some_string * -r
en:some_string=Some string
```

How can I remove the hidden svn diretories from my output, and not only from the first depth level?

```
$ grep some_string * -r --which_option_here?
lang/en:some_string=Some string
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you may want to try [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).

Answer (score 37):

Use `--exclude-dir` option, e.g.:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' some_string
```

From `man grep`:

```
--exclude-dir=DIR
              Exclude directories matching the pattern DIR from recursive searches.
```

Note however, that `--exclude-dir` option is available only in GNU grep. If your `grep` doesn't support it, you may need to use other tool as find [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565471/how-can-i-exclude-directories-from-grep-r/6565519#6565519):

```
find . \( -name .svn -prune \) -o -name "*" -exec grep -H "some_string" {} 2>/dev/null \;
```

Comment: I must have a too old Linux...

Comment: I have edited the answer, try the `find` version if your grep doesn't support `--exclude-dir`.

Comment: I have version grep version 2.5.1, and there is no --exclude-dir argument, and I have tried everything I thought of...

Comment: Second solution doesn't use `--exclude-dir`, have you tried it?

Comment: I have "unreconized option"

Comment: That's because the `-H` option is also available only with `gnu grep`. Try it with `grep "pattern" /dev/null {}...` instead of `grep -H "pattern" {}...`

Comment: side note: `grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' .` will exclude everything, because everything starts with `./` when you specify `.` as an explicit path argument. So be careful not to specify the current directory explicitly, or use an exclusion pattern like `--eclude-dir='.?*'`, which matches and excludes only dirs with at least one character after the dot.

Comment: This did not work for me on a Fedora.  I used `--exclude-dir='.[^.]*'` instead.

Comment: This absolutely fails when using on the current directory `.` (big use case). It will ALWAYS return NOTHING.

Comment: I just learned that if you don't pass any argument for the directory, grep still works on the current directory (but doesn't face the exclude current directory problem). So I guess with this workaround it's not a big use case.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use this:

```
for e in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d); do echo ${e#\./}; done | grep -v '^\.'
```

`${e%\./}` will remove the first `./` and then `grep` removes everything that begins with a dot.

Comment: Code says `e#`, text says `e%`

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, I'm using:

```
grep -lR --exclude-dir={'*node_modules*',build,'./.*'} 'SearchTerm'
```