# Exclude all hidden directories with grep and pcregrep

Tags: grep, wildcards, pcregrep

I'm trying to exclude all hidden directories from recursive search.

I think `.*/\..*` this should match hidden directories and this indeed works with find, however grep doesn't think so.

`pcregrep -rnI -C 5 --exclude-dir='.*/\..*' '^\s*async def' .`

`grep -rnIP -C 5 --exclude-dir=*/.* '^\s*def' .`

What am I doing wrong here?

Oh, and I know about ripgrep, silver searcher etc. The question is about grep and pcregrep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude hidden subdirectories from grep -r](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158638/exclude-hidden-subdirectories-from-grep-r)

Comment: @AJefferiss Yeah I've seen this answer. It's not a duplicate. The answer in the linked question is `.*` which would exclude current directory which starts with `.` and wouldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -r --exclude-dir='^\..' pattern .
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='.[^.]*' pattern .
```

Please note that the meaning of `--exclude-dir` is different for `pcregrep` and `grep`.  Read the corresponding manuals for details.

Comment: Worth noting that `grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' pattern` works fine too - that is, using `'.*'` as exclude pattern and omitting the `.` argument

Comment: @don_crissti Oh, I didn't know about ommiting directory, thanks. I've solved it with `$(pwd)` but this is better

Comment: @user1685095 - no problem, it's really easy to overlook: _"if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory"_ - keep in mind though that Sato's solution is the proper way to do it and the only way to make it work if you want to use `grep -r` on a list of directories which includes `.` (that is the cwd)

Comment: @don_crissti Also IIRC `grep`-ing in the current directory when you don't specify a starting point is a GNU extension.