# Excluding two kind of directories using regular expressions with grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348597/exclude-all-hidden-directories-with-grep-and-pcregrep) SE answer made me realize I can exclude directories using regular expressions with grep. But it's not working for me when using `|`:

```
results=$(grep --color=always -rnF "$searchTerm" . --exclude-dir='.[^.]*|node_modules')
results=$(grep --color=always -rnF "$searchTerm" . --exclude-dir='.[^.]*\|node_modules')
```

Is there another way to write this regex so that I exclude directories that start with a period and node_modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for GNU grep, `--exclude` appears to expect a glob pattern not a regex - the answer to your linked question alludes to that where it says *"Please note that the meaning of --exclude-dir is different for pcregrep and grep. Read the corresponding manuals for details."*. Specifically:

In `man grep`:

> ```
>   --exclude-dir=GLOB
>           Skip any command-line directory with a name suffix that  matches
>           the   pattern   GLOB.   When  searching  recursively,  skip  any
>           subdirectory whose base name matches GLOB.  Ignore any redundant
>           trailing slashes in GLOB.
> ```

In `man pcregrep`:

> ```
>    --exclude=pattern
>              Files (but not directories) whose names match the pattern are
>              skipped  without  being processed. This applies to all files,
>              whether listed on the command  line,  obtained  from  --file-
>              list, or by scanning a directory. The pattern is a PCRE regu‐
>              lar expression, and is matched against the final component of
>              the  file  name,  not the entire path.
> ```

At least in GNU grep, you can however use `--exclude-dir` multiple times if you want to exclude multiple patterns:

```
--exclude-dir='.?*' --exclude-dir='node_modules'
```

I've changed the `.[^.]*` to `.?*` as:

- There's no point trying not to exclude `..` if that was the intention, as you're searching in the current directory here (omitting the target files with `-r` defaults to `.` in recent versions of GNU `grep`, except that I find that with GNU `grep` 3.11 at least, even `--exclude-dir='*'` fails to exclude it, so even `--exclude-dir='.*'` would be enough with that version if you didn't specify any target directory).
- that would fail to exclude directories named `..foo` or `...`
- the POSIX glob equivalent of regex `[^.]` is `[!.]` (though `[^.]` is often supported as well at least on GNU systems).

Comment: Thanks @stéphane-chazelas - to be honest, I didn't really look at the patterns themselves - my bad

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `find` ?

```
tree -a
.
├── node_modules
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
├── .test
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
└── x
    ├── 001
    └── 002

3 directories, 8 files
```

```
find . \( ! -path './node_modules*' -a ! -path './.*' \)
.
./x
./x/002
./x/001
```

Finally:

```
find . \( ! -path './node_modules*' -a ! -path './.*' \) \
    -exec grep --color=always -nF "$searchTerm" {} +
```

Comment: Those exclude `./.dir` but not `./foo/.dir`. Doing it like that instead of doing `LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o ...` also means `find` still descends into those directories

Comment: It depends of the filter. To avoid all, OP need `! -path */.*'`