# How to recursively grep current directory contents, omitting all hidden directories?

Tags: grep

Following the advice under [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158638/exclude-hidden-subdirectories-from-grep-r) question, I am able to recursively grep for a string `string` within contents of a given directory `dir` as follows

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' string dir
```

However, when I apply this to the current directory, as

```
$ grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' string .
$
```

I get no results, since the `--exclude-dir='.*'` option omits the current directory as hidden since it matches `'.*'`.

A work-around is to change to the parent directory via `cd ..`, then run the command on the appropriate child, then `cd` again back into that original working directory. There must be a single-command that I can use to do this without the work-around of changing directories.

**What is a single command to grep contents of the current directory, omitting contents of hidden directories?**

Answer (score 4):

If you’re using GNU grep 2.11 or later, `-r` will start from the current directory if no directory is specified:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' string
```

Comment: Good on including the version note.  With BSD `grep` it produces: `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin`

Answer (score 2):

Since `bash` won't have `grep` traverse hidden directories by default (i. e. without `dotglob` enabled:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── .test
│   ├── .file
│   └── file
├── file
└── test
    ├── .file
    └── file

2 directories, 5 files

$ grep -r foo *
file:foo
test/.file:foo
test/file:foo
```

Just exclude hidden files:

```
$ grep --exclude=".*" -r foo *
file:foo
test/file:foo
```

Comment: I am curious as to the reasoning behind the uncommented downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not true that `grep` doesn't traverse hidden directories.  What you're seeing with `grep -r foo *` is that the *shell glob* `*` doesn't expand to include hidden directories/files, *unless* `dotglob` has been set with `shopt -s dotglob`.  Try with `grep -r foo .` and you'll see the hidden directories *are* traversed by grep.  Or, try with `shopt -s dotglob` and then `grep -r foo *`.

Comment: Fair point; I have clarified this in my answer.

Comment: This will still search files in hidden directories contained within the command line arguments.  It will *sort of* work.  For most cases it might be okay, but it's like defining "pi" as "3.1416"; you better know the caveats.

Answer (score 2):

In shell glob (also known as filename patterns), `.` has no special meaning, `*` means zero or more characters, and `?` means any single character.

What you want to exclude is a dot followed by *at least one* character, and then any number of characters.  So use:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='.?*' string .
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also specify the current directory using `$(pwd)` like:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' string "$(pwd)"
```

Comment: Quote your command substitution: `"$(pwd)"`  See also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Answer (score 1):

To recurse inside a **single** directory (not limiting sub-diredtories hidden files) use:

As `echo dir/*` will print all files inside dir, this will work for files inside some dir:

```
$ grep -r "string" $(echo dir/*)
```

just change `dir` to `.` (dot) and you will get exactly what you want:

```
$ grep -r "string" $(echo ./*)
```

If what is needed is no hidden files in any of the sub-directories, either use:

```
$ grep -r --exclude-dir='.*' "string"
```

Or use find:

```
find . -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -exec grep "string" {} \+
```